# Connect to SQL Server Instance on AWS Workspace

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssms, amazon-workspaces

I have an AWS Workspace running an application that uses a local SQL Server database.  I would like to connect to that database from my local machine using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

On the AWS Workspace I have (1) enabled TCP/IP (SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for [INSTANCE]), keeping the default port of 1433, and (2) allowed communication on that port through the firewall.

In my AWS Dashboard I have (1) assigned an Elastic IP Address to the Network Interface used by that Workspace and (2) set up an Inbound Rule for port 1433 from my local IP Address in the Security Group settings.

When I try to connect to that instance from my local SSMS I enter:
Server name:  [Elastic IP Address]:1433[INSTANCE]
Authentication:  SQL Server Authentication
Login:  [Workspaces User]
Password: [Workspaces User Password]

and I get

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> ---
>
> Cannot connect to *[Elastic IP Address]:1433[INSTANCE]*.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=87&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> The parameter is incorrect
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> OK
>
> ---

I feel like I'm just missing one step, but can't figure out what it is.  I've tried a few variations in the Connect Object Explorer window.
**I am now confident the issue is with the port on the Workspace.**

Extra Info:
Using Portqry.exe returns "FILTERED".
I've tried enabling Named Pipes in SQL Server Configuration Manager as well.
This is the default instance of SSQL Server on the Workspace.
For troubleshooting purposes, I opened port 1433 to everyone in Security Group settings; on canyouseeme.org from the Workspace, it is showing that it CANNOT see on port 1433.

Comment: When connecting in SSMS try using server: `ElasticIpAddress,1433` (note the comma). Also make sure that you have Security Groups configured to allow tcp/1433 access from your workspace to the SQL Server's subnet and instance.

Comment: Also, if you changed any configuration in SQL Server Manager > Server Protocols you'll need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take affect.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for responding.  I did restart after making the changes and the security group is configured.  I tried the comma instead of the colon, but still unsuccessful.